# Nativescript RadListView input element value jumps when scrolling

Tags: angular, nativescript, radlistview

I am trying to build a list using RadListView with TextField and TextView in each row/cell. The list displays correctly but when the list is long enough to scroll and I enter anything in the input fields, such as “hello” and I scroll, the “hello” will randomly move around to a different item.

Example:
List with 50 rows. I enter “hello” in the textfield of row 1. I scroll down so that row 1 is not visible any more. “hello” appears in textfield of row 12. I scroll back to row 1 and text field is empty. I scroll down to row 12 and its empty but “hello” now shows up in textfield of row 18…etc

Here is the code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";


class DataItem {
constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
}

@Component({
selector: "orderpage_rad",
template: `
<StackLayout>
<RadListView [items]="myItems">
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item" let-i="index">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label [text]='"index: " + i'></Label>
        <Label [text]='"name: " + item.name'></Label>
        <TextField keyboardType="number" hint="quantity"></TextField>            
        <TextView hint="enter text" editable="true"></TextView>             
    </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>                
</RadListView>
</StackLayout>
`    
})

export class orderComponent_rad {


public myItems: Array<DataItem>;
private counter: number;

constructor(){

    this.myItems = [];
    this.counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        this.myItems.push(new DataItem(i, "data item " + i));
        this.counter = i;
    }            
}

}
```

I am getting the same results with the normal nativescript ListView, so I don't think its a bug.

How can I correct this?

I am using Angular with Typescript and so far only testing on Android:

tns --version: 3.1.2

Cross-platform modules version: 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found a solution with the help from, Hamdi W. All credit goes to him.

Here it is for anybody that might have the same issue in the future:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {TextField} from 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-field';

class ProductItem {
 constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string, 
    public quantity: number
) { }
}

@Component({
selector: "Home",
moduleId: module.id,
template: `
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text='submit' (tap)="submit()"></Label>
        <ListView [items]="products">
            <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label [text]='"name: " + item.name'></Label>
                    <TextField keyboardType="number"
                               [id]='item.id'
                               [hint]="'quantity' + i"
                               [text]='item.quantity'
                               (returnPress)="onReturn($event)"
                    </TextField>
                    <Label [text]='item.quantity'></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
`
})
export class HomeComponent{
public products: Array<ProductItem>;

constructor(){
    this.products = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        this.products.push(new ProductItem(i, "data item " + i, i));
    }
}

private submit()
{
    //send to server this.products
}

public onReturn(args) {
    const {id, text} = <TextField>args.object;

    this.products = this.products.map(product => {
        if(product.id === parseInt(id)){
            product.quantity = parseInt(text);
        }
        return product;
    });
}
}
```

The solution is the onReturn() function and you can change (returnPress)="onReturn($event)" to (textChange)="onReturn($event)"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler answer I found, we can get the same using Nativescript 2 way binding:

We remove this function: (returnPress)="onReturn($event)" and this [text]='item.quantity' and replace with [(ngModel)]="products[i].quantity"

Now any changes made in the TextField will automatically update the object and the listview will use the new value when it needs to render the element again.

Here is the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {TextField} from 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-field';

class ProductItem {
constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string, 
    public quantity: number
) { }
}

@Component({
selector: "orderpage_rad",
moduleId: module.id,
template: `
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text='submit' (tap)="submit()"></Label>
        <ListView [items]="products">
            <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label [text]='"name: " + item.name'></Label>
                    <TextField keyboardType="number"
                               [id]='item.id'
                               [hint]="'quantity' + i"
                               [(ngModel)]="products[i].quantity">
                    </TextField>
                    <Label [text]='item.quantity'></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
 `
})
export class orderComponent_rad{
public products: Array<ProductItem>;

constructor(){
    this.products = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        this.products.push(new ProductItem(i, "data item " + i, i));
    }
}

}
```